# add class/id via javascript/jquery to div with specific text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to customize a specific page by injecting it with javascript/jQuery to add a css class/id to a specific "div" in the sidebar. I've copied and pasted the code on [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7j0wwtna/). Im trying to ONLY add "nodisplay" class/id to the blue highlighted box ([see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XZtF.jpg)) so I can hide it via css.

I can NOT use the "[nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)" css selector because that blue box is sometimes displayed first, or sometimes displayed second, etc. I want to ADD "nodisplay" to the parent div ONLY IF the first child div contains text "Manage".

logic:

```
if div.SidebarList-sidebarListHeader-m1Kth contains text that matches exactly = "Manage",
then add "nodisplay" to parent div css;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains`  to check desire text and use `parent` to find parent.

```js
if ($(".menu:contains('Sed')")) {
  $('.menu').parent().addClass('dclass');
}
```

```css
.dclass {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>   
 <div class='menu'>
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("div:contains('my text')").closest('div')`. See the [jQuery :contains API](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and the [jQuery .closest() API](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 0):

I add code sample for you.

```
$('.SidebarList-sidebarListHeader-m1Kth:contains("Manage")').parent().addClass("nodisplay");
```

check here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j0wwtna/26/)

Comment: nodispaly class is added to 'Manage' text parent div. what else you want.

Comment: instead of "display: none", i made "background: blue" so you can see that it's choosing everything, instead of the first group (manage, status, settings)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7j0wwtna/26/ now try. this is what you want. i think.

Answer (score 0):

The .closest() function is the immediate parent of element.

```
$("div.SidebarList-sidebarListHeader-m1Kth:contains('Manage')").closest("div").addClass("nodisplay");
```

Comment: @1xxooxx You need to include jquery to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will works for you,

```
$('.SidebarList-sidebarListHeader-m1Kth').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Manage';
}).parent('div').hide();
```

click here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5f5k7vn/1/)

Comment: you have to add jquery reference other wise wont work. Add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to your html page

Comment: check the fiddle page I have given.